# Cut out with correct UV/Material

Tags: mesh, materials, uv, svg

I want to "cut out" a letter from a wooden material (image texture). I imported a letter as SVG and turned it into a mesh. Now I want the letter to look like it was cut out from the wooden board underneath, with the exact Texture Coordinates, so the texture of the wood and the texture of the letter match correctly. (My approach was to use the image texture from the wooden panel for the letter and play with the coordinates until everything matches but that does not seem to be an efficient method. Furthermore, it seems impossible to apply any image texture to the letter due its the "zigzag pattern". Any help is very much appreciated.

[image: Image1]
[image: Image2]
[image: Image3]

Comment: You can probably remove the "zig zag" pattern by using a _Decimate_ modifier set to "planar" (View it from object mode - wireframe to see what it's doing before applying). The rest, you'll likely have to do with manual UV scaling/alignment.

Comment: The way to make it match the block underneath depends on the material used for that block-- you might consider including an image of its material nodes.  The top of the C should be easily matchable, but there's no simple automatic solution for the sides of the C.

Comment: You should be able to select both the letter and the plane underneath and unwrap them together, choose the Project From View option